# WiFi/Internet access elementary OS

Tags: internet

I installed elementary OS v5 on a Dell Latitude E6410. The program indicates that it recognizes the wireless network and is connected, but when I attempt to access any site it displays the message "unable to display this website" Also, when I search for networks in my area my network is listed twice as "network name." and "network name 1".

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Elementary OS forums!

What happens if you go to Applications -> Terminal and issue the command

```
nmcli d wifi list
```

If the result of that command has the data you expect in the following areas: SSID, CHAN, BARS, SECURITY that is the first step.  For the second step, what are the results of this command (also in terminal).

```
ping -c 3 8.8.8.8
```

Please let us know.